# ReactMarkdown without wrapping div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I'm using `ReactMarkdown` component (https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).

It works correct. Except that all output is wrapped with a `div`.

After research i found the solution:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution:

ReactMarkdown accepts a prop "renderers". You can pass an object with keys for every node type.
And when you set the key "root" to React.Fragment it renders all flat. Without the wrapping div:

```
<ReactMarkdown source={myMdString} renderers={{ root: React.Fragment }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version does not support custom root. According to [sources](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/blob/a3de85b4d77486ce26f4efa9c8ab07f8e40ad061/lib/react-markdown.js#L119) it uses `div` if there is a className property and `React.Fragment` otherwise.

So in my case I had to remove the className

Comment: Would you mind providing your source?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Yozi! It's not pretty, but adding `className={undefined}` to `<ReactMarkdown />` removed the container `div`.